# Passing function object references as serialized json

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I have written some widgets using the jquery widget factory. Normally, I pass options and callback references using the widget constructor in a JavaScript code block.

Now I want to use the widgets in auto generated html pages and pass options to them without using JavaScript blocks. I am specifying the options in embedded json which a common JavaScript code block parses and passes it on to the widget.

```
<div id="search_widget">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
        "search": {
            "search_string": "text to be searched",
            "callback": "a function object in an outer scope"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

How do I pass the function objects preserving their scope to the widgets in json format ?
The widget will then call the function specified when a condition is met.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Function.prototype.toJSON= ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the function body as text, but your receiving context will have to know it's a function and "reconstitute" it with the `Function` constructor (or something). You can't preserve the "scope", though that doesn't really mean much in a block of JSON.

You could also pass the function name, or some identifying pattern, or anything else you like, but all on the condition that the receiving code knows how to act on that.

JSON provides no mechanism for representing a "function".  The concept is completely alien to the format, and rightly so, as it's intended to be language-neutral.

*edit* — Note that if you encode your function by name:

```
<script type="application/json">
{
    "search": {
        "search_string": "text to be searched",
        "callback": "search_callback_23"
    }
}
</script>
```

Then the code that grabs the object and interprets the contents can always invoke the function with the outer JSON object as the context:

```
function handleJSON( the_JSON_from_the_example ) {
  var json = JSON.parse(the_JSON_from_the_example);
  if ("search" in json) {
    var searchTerm = json.search.search_string;
    var callback = findCallbackFunction(json.search.callback); // whatever 
    callback.call(json, searchTerm); // or json.search maybe?
  }
}
```

In other words, if the code that's interpreting the JSON-encoded information knows enough to find callback function references, then it can probably figure out an appropriate object to use as `this` when it calls the function.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, but passing the function body is not an option. Is it possible to pass a function name and some indication of the scope so that I can proxy the method call ?

Comment: @user2631483 as long as the receiving environment has a way to understand how your JSON identifies functions, then yes you can do whatever (so long as the representation involves just strings and numbers and booleans).  You'll have to explain more about what you mean by "scope", because there's really no such thing in JSON.

Comment: By scope, I meant somehow passing the 'this' object using json. But as you rightly say there would be no such thing in JSON.

Comment: @user2631483 right, but since ... oh well I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, for the elaboration. The approach you suggest will work.